# Angular build for subfolder

Tags: angular, angular-cli, progressive-web-apps, angular17

I've an Angular 17 app that runs well on my domain.
I now wanted to run a second build within a subfolder of my webserver like mydomain.com/pwa1

Since the default base-href is `<base href="/">`  I run a build with `ng build --base-href='./pwa1'` (also tried `'pwa1'` `'/pwa1'` and `'./pwa1/'`).

Then I copied the results into the subfolder `pwa1`.

But now, if I call mydomain.com/pwa1 the url immediately changes to `/pwa1/pwa1` - but the running app (webpage) itself look good and seems to work. Nevertheless, the pwa stuff fails, since it obviosly cannot find any files within `'pwa1/pwa1'` - this folder doesn't exist.

Why is this happen? And isn't this the best practice to create a second build for a subfolder?

Comment: You may have .htaccess or similar kind of rule applied to your subdomain.